# What does '\' mean when declaring a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, variable-declaration, data-preprocessing

While I was searching code from the internet about YouTube data analysis, I found code like this:

```
df_rgb2['total_sign_comment_ratio'] = df_rgb2['total_number_of_sign'] / df_rgb2['comment_count']

total_sign_comment_ratio_max = df_rgb2['total_sign_comment_ratio'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0).max()

df_rgb2['total_sign_comment_ratio'] = \

df_rgb2['total_sign_comment_ratio'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], total_sign_comment_ratio_max*1.5)
```

and I was wondering why the analyst used the expression:

```
df_rgb2['total_sign_comment_ratio'] = \
```

because whether I apply that code or not, the result is same.

I tried to find the meaning of `'\'` but all I have got is how to use `'\'` when printing out the result.

Comment: \ is used to break code on multiple lines

Comment: What you have right now is a syntax error, because the continued line isn't actually completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is usually used to make a piece of code go on onto multiple lines. If you where to just press enter and continue to write code a line below for example declaring a variable, it would count as an error.

You use this when you need to tidy up code or when your working window is too small for some reason.

See: https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-statements/

Comment: *"You use this when you need to tidy up code"* -- Well, you use it as a last resort. First you should use parentheses, per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), *"Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."*